# Displaying by DateTime.now - Silverlight WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, where-clause

Ok, So I want to display some attributes, but only if they have a start time of today's date.

Is there a way to use a wildcard for value? or List multiple values in a Where clause?

Here is an example.. I was thinking if I could pull the current time and then convert to string ( var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");) I could use that var as a filter for the attribute. here ... where tv.Attribute("start").Value == time

EDIT ********

I have updated to the code to make it a little clearer what I am after. As you can see below I am using a Where clause to display attributes under related to a specific "start" time.

Now this example won't work for me because first it need to be all listings over a 24 hour period not a specfic time as below and also because I want to dynamically display listings by DateTime.Now.

So, what I really need is a way to display the current day, but not specific time as a bool and use that in my boolean equation to display "start" attributes by current day.

```
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadStringCompleted);
            c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.domain.com/source.xml"));
            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


        } 


        void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;


            var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);


            listBox2.ItemsSource = from tv in r.Root.Descendants("programme")
                                   where tv.Attribute("start").Value == "20110724190000 +1200"
                                   let channelE1 = tv.Attribute("channel")
                                   let startE1 = tv.Attribute("start")
                                   let nameEl = tv.Element("title")
                                   orderby tv.Attribute("start").Value ascending
                                   let urlEl = tv.Element("desc")


                                   select new TV1guide



                                   {
                                       DisplayName = nameEl == null ? null : nameEl.Value,
                                       ChannelName = channelE1 == null ? null : channelE1.Value,
                                       ChannelURL = urlEl == null ? null : urlEl.Value,
                                       StartTime = startE1 == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(startE1.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal),



                                   };

            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
            progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

public class TV1guide
        {
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string ChannelURL { get; set; }
            public string ImageSource { get; set; }
            public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
            public string ChannelName { get; set; }

        }

    }

}
```

As well as this I have also tried what HiTech Magic suggested, but Im pretty sure the syntax is wrong.

```
                WebClient c = new WebClient();
                c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadStringCompleted);
                c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.domain.com/source.xml"));
                progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
                progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


            } 

bool MyDateCheckingMethod( DateTime otherDate )
{
    // Is this today (ignoring time)?
    return otherDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date;
}

void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    return;


                var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);


                listBox2.ItemsSource = from tv in r.Root.Descendants("programme")
                                       where MyDateCheckingMethod(tv.Attribute("start").Value)
                                       let channelE1 = tv.Attribute("channel")
                                       let startE1 = tv.Attribute("start")
                                       let nameEl = tv.Element("title")
                                       orderby tv.Attribute("start").Value ascending
                                       let urlEl = tv.Element("desc")


                                       select new TV1guide



                                       {
                                           DisplayName = nameEl == null ? null : nameEl.Value,
                                           ChannelName = channelE1 == null ? null : channelE1.Value,
                                           ChannelURL = urlEl == null ? null : urlEl.Value,
                                           StartTime = startE1 == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(startE1.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal),



                                       };

                progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
                progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public class TV1guide
            {
                public string DisplayName { get; set; }
                public string ChannelURL { get; set; }
                public string ImageSource { get; set; }
                public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
                public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
                public string ChannelName { get; set; }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ plays well with all C# functions, so it can be as simple as:

```
where MyListOfDates.Contains(tv.Attribute("start").Value)
```

and just put all the required dates into a `List<DateTime> MyListOfDates`

If you want to use some other comparison and not just a basic list, place the logic into a Method and call that e.g.:

```
where MyDateCheckingMethod(tv.Attribute("start").Value)
```

The "Date/Time" value you get from your XML parsing is actually a string in "yyyyMMddHHmmss K" format so your method might look like:

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
{
    DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
    // Is this today (ignoring time)?
    return otherDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date;
}
```

Comment: That would mean having a list of 48, 2 for every hour of the day, as I want it disaply all listings by day. It would also mean that I would have to change it everyday. Is there a way to use DateTime.Now and use a variation of the current time?

Comment: @Rhys: Please see the second part. You can have "any" comparison you care to invent yourself. Just place the logic in a method and/or just use the `Date` only part of the DateTime.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. How would I use that in my Where clause though? I tried<code> where tv.Attribute("start").Value == MydateCheckingMethod <code> but I get error. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Rhys: Can you please add an update to your question showing exactly what you are trying? That will make it easier to correct.

Comment: I have just updated my code and tried to clarify what I am trying to achieve

Comment: MagicAny more suggestions or are you stumped? :)

Comment: Any Luck ? Im struggling with this one

Comment: You want something like `where MyDateCheckingMethod(tv.Attribute("start").Value)`. Not `where tv.Attribute("start").Value == MyDateCheckingMethod`

Comment: Still not working.. Now getting **Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Comment: I have updated the code to show the changes you suggested. Is it possible for you to test my code on your end? Just to see if you can replicate the issue? I know its a big ask, but If you could that would be great.

Comment: Works great, just what I was after, Thanks very much for your help.